# How to run cssify with babelify

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I'm building a widget using React and I'm using the following command to compile my code:

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] input.js -o output.js
```

But now I also need to load stylesheet from the component itself. I found cssify for this purpose. Now I have the following line on my code:

```
var style = require('./styles/widget.css');
```

I already have cssify installed and I've appended the command right after babelify:

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] cssify ] input.js -o output.js
```

This doesn't seem to work though.

Any ideas? I'd rather not deal with setting up webpack, gulp or any other build tool right now. But if there's really no other way to do it other than that then please show me how
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to specify my transforms one by one, not sure if there is a shorthand for it.

```
browserify -t babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] -t cssify input.js > output.js
```

To clean that up a little I normally add it as a script to the package and add a babel field

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "browserify -t babelify -t cssify input.js > output.js"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```